# Android Date/Time picker that is not a dialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I want to add the time and the date picker of Android in my main view and display it always. Now it works only as a dialog. Is there any way to use it as a view and not a dialog?

Is there any library that can do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a Date widget and time widget present in Layout Manager

Comment: see this : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/

Answer (score 6):

You can add date picker and time picker in your layout

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

you can set them according to your requirments

Answer (score 3):

Try this way..this is the way you can create without dailog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

TimePickerDemoActivity.java

```
public class TimePickerDemoActivity extends Activity implements
    OnTimeChangedListener {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TimePicker picker=(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.picker);

    picker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Calendar then=Calendar.getInstance();

    then.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    then.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    then.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Toast.makeText(this, then.getTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show();
  }
}
```